# Is there a symbol for the median of a population?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, median, notation

We usually use $\mu$ for the population mean but I couldn't find a symbol the median of a population. Is it ok to use just $m$? For instance,

$H_o: \ m_{a} = m_{b}$

$H_a: \ m_{a} <> m_{b}$

is it Ok to formulate these hypotheses like that?

Comment: Personally, I like it.  But you're not just going to drop these symbols in out of nowhere, right?  You'll follow up with "where $m_a$ is the median value for population $a$"?

Comment: The world is too big, rich, and complicated to allow us to reserve our limited numbers of symbols for specific purposes.  That is why people *describe* and *define* their terminology.  That also allows you the creativity to use whatever notation you think might best convey your ideas to your audience.  Thus, hypotheses formulated as you have shown are in themselves meaningless, but when accompanied by your explanation of what $m_a$ and $m_b$ refer to, are perfectly fine.

Comment: @The Laconic, yes, $m_a$ stands for the median value for population a.

Comment: @whuber. Yes, but as there is the $\mu$ symbol for the mean, I supposed there would be some symbol for the median. Maybe the median is underused compared to the mean?

Comment: I know $m_a$ is the median value for population $a$, but only from the context of the question.  My point is that you can use whatever symbol you want as long as you tell the reader what you're doing.  Which is @whuber's point.  And PS I like $m$ just fine.

Comment: Agreeing with everyone, I'd say that sometimes it is convenient to use ``m`` for the sample mean, especially when typesetting code (shorter to write ``mx`` than ``x_bar``, ``x.bar`` or ``xbar``), and some authors do use it for consistency (as in: sigma --> s, beta --> b, mu --> m). For that reason, I'd avoid using ``m`` for the median. I would favour capital ``M`` or go for an explicit ``Med`` or ``med``. Or tilde. But either way, you must define it clearly.

Answer (score 5):

I have seen a number of symbols used to denote the population median.

One I have seen quite a few times is $\tilde\mu$, but as whuber suggests in comments, you should define whatever you do use. So if you were to use this suggestion, you could say something like:

> $H_0: \ \tilde{\mu}_{a} = \tilde{\mu}_{b}$
>   $H_a: \ \tilde{\mu}_{a} \neq \tilde{\mu}_{b}$
>
> $\text{where }\tilde{\mu}\text{ denotes the population median.}$

It would be okay to use $m$ for that, just as you have it in your question (as long as you define it) -- though keep in mind that conventionally population quantities are denoted by Greek symbols, which is probably why $\tilde\mu$ tends to crop up.

You'd also need to be clear (somewhere) about the meaning of the subscripts $_a$ and $_b$. (Note also the use of $\neq$ in preference to $<>$.)

Comment: I've never seen $\tilde{\mu}$ as the population median, but sometimes I've seen $m$. The bar, as in $\bar{x}$ is usually used for sample mean, the tilde, I don't know. Anyway, I think you're right about population parameters written using Greek symbols. I think that $\mu$, as being the lower case for $M$ in the Greek alphabet, is ok to denote the median too. Furthermore, R language uses mu as a parameter for some statistical test Indistinctly for mean or median.

Comment: There's a distinction between  $\bar{\ }$ (bar) and $\tilde{\ }$ (tilde) over something. They're not at all the same symbol. The first *is* used to denote sample means but the second is used for a variety of purposes, often as some sort of variant of a more common thing, including $\tilde{x}$ representing the sample median (akin to but distinct from $\bar{x}$ for the sample mean). It is also sometimes used to denote a population median by analogy to that use.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently in an introduction to statistics class and the textbook says that the median of a statistic can be represented with an "M" (a capital m). And the median of a parameter can be represented with a "θ" (a theta). This is as straightforward of an answer as you are going to get, though I am sure the way you handled the situation would work just fine also.

Answer (score 0):

The Greek letter Eta (η) can also be used to represent the population median. Check this from Wikipedia: In Statistics, η2 is the "partial regression coefficient". η is the symbol for the linear predictor of a generalized linear model, and can also be used to denote the median of a population, or thresholding parameter in Sparse Partial Least Squares regression.

Comment: I don't understand the value of the question but I have nothing against your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the median as $Q(a,50\%)$, i.e. the 50th percentile, and write the null hypothesis as:
$$H_0: Q(a,50\%)=Q(b,50\%)$$
This notation is longer than the other notations here, but its meaning is probably more obvious. So you probably would want to clarify that $Q$ is the quantile function, but readers might understand the reference to the median automatically.